# To set value written by user as value of dropdown in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a Remarks div
[If user choose option of Other then user need to fill box for reasons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWKsJ.png)

**This is inside webpage(.cshtml)**

```
    @model MNepalWeb.Models.CustomerSRInfo
@{
List<SelectListItem> Remarks = new List<SelectListItem>();
    Remarks.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Your name does not match", Value = "Your name does not match" });
    Remarks.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Your date of birth does not match", Value = "Your date of birth does not match" });
    Remarks.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Others", Value = "Others" });
}
```

**//For remarks**

```
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-2">Reject Remarks <b style="color:red;">*</b></label>

                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Remarks, new SelectList(Remarks, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 100%;", @id = "txtRemarks" })
                                    <br />
                                    <textarea name="OthersRemarks" id="txtOthersRemarks" placeholder="Please Insert Remarks to Reject, maxlength- 200" maxlength="200" rows="4" cols="50" style=" display:none; min-height:50px;min-width:200px;max-height:100px;max-width:422px;" class="form-control" @*oninput="checkValidation()"*@></textarea>
                                    <b style="color:red">*</b><b> Note Please fill out remarks before rejecting </b>
                                    <br />
                                </div>
                               </div>
                        </div>
```

**JS for changing value**

```
if ($.trim($('#RejectRemarks select').val()) == "" || $.trim($('#RejectRemarks select').val()) == "Others") {
                   var TextBoxRemarks = $("#txtOthersRemarks").val();
                   if ($.trim($('#RejectRemarks select').val()) == "Others" && TextBoxRemarks.trim() == "") {
                       document.getElementById("txtOthersRemarks").setCustomValidity("Other Reject Remarks is required");
                       $('#txtOthersRemarks select').focus();
                       return;
                   }
                   else if ($.trim($('#RejectRemarks select').val()) == "Others" && TextBoxRemarks.trim() != "") {
                       var txtRemarks = document.getElementById("txtRemarks");
                       //txtRemarks.value = $("#txtOthersRemarks").val();
                       txtRemarks.val = TextBoxRemarks; 
                       //txtRemarks.value = TextBoxRemarks;
                       document.getElementById("txtOthersRemarks").setCustomValidity("");

                       return;
                   }
                   else {
                       document.getElementById("txtRemarks").setCustomValidity("Reject Remarks is required");
                       $('#RejectRemarks select').focus();
                       return;
                   }
               }
               else {
                   document.getElementById("txtRemarks").setCustomValidity("");

               }
```

But when i implement this js it only changes values to checkbox and not send empty value to controller.

```
public ActionResult BankLinkVerify(UserInfo model, string btnApprove, string Remarks)
```

I'm trying to find where it goes wrong but could not analysis this. I need whatever user types in text box as remarks value.( default it goes other but when i do that js dropdown value goes null to controller). 
Thank You!

Comment: How are you sending the form data to the Controller method? Are you using AJAX or default form binding?

Comment: @RahulSharma. Sir I use form binding

Comment: @RahulSharma.. using (Html.BeginForm("BankLinkVerify", "Customer", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ViewBankLinkVerifyDetail", class = "ViewBankLinkVerifyDetail" }))

Comment: You can use FormCollection to get your value: `string Remarks= Request.Form["Remarks"].ToString();`

Comment: @RahulSharma. Sir, it gives the value as "others" whereas i need what user types in textbox as remarks .. Suppose User select other in dropdown and types something like "Image doesnot match with citizenship" then.. Remarks value should be changed to what user types whereas i am getting only "other" as value. i tried to change value  but only getting empty value.

Comment: Okay for that try this: `string Remarks= Request.Form["txtOthersRemarks"].ToString()`

Comment: @RahulSharma. Great sir. thank you! I will filter that out. if remarks is "other" i will replace that value through controller. string Remarks= Request.Form["OthersRemarks"].ToString(); this helps to get value.. thank you for your time and help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your case, you can access the current value through the `Request` or `FormCollection`. You can read your `OthersRemarks` textarea value from the current Request using `Request.Form`:

In your `Controller` method:

```
string Remarks= Request.Form["OthersRemarks"].ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution too..

FormCollection can also be used in controller

```
public ActionResult BankLinkApprove(UserInfo model, string btnApprove, FormCollection collection, string Remarks){

        if (Remarks.Equals("Others")){
        userInfo.Remarks = collection["OthersRemarks"].ToString();
        }
        else{
        userInfo.Remarks = info.Remarks;
        }
}
```